# Нужно ли тире в предложении с приложением

Tags: приложение

Сегодня похоронили талантливого актера и комедианта (-) Анатолия Викторовича Пронина.

Можно прочитать без паузы, и тогда тире ставить не нужно. А если же все-таки мы поставим паузу после "комедианта", логически выделив приложение. Комедианта (какого) Анатолия Викторовича Пронина. ТО нужно ли будет ставить тире или постановка этого тире будет зависеть от смысла, который вкладывает автор?

P.S. Речь не об авторском знаке, а о стандартных правилах!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.  Можно ли не ставить тире?**

*Сегодня похоронили  / талантливого актера и комедианта  / **Анатолия Викторовича Пронина.***

Да, можно. Интонационный анализ показывает, что прочитать предложение можно и **без тире** (на схеме показано деление предложения на смысловые отрезки при чтении).

**2. Но автор текста ставит тире, а зачем?**

Сравним с другим предложением: *В Москве в возрасте 65 лет / ушел из жизни актер и режиссер  / Рустам Уразаев.*

Разница  в элементах **художественного** стиля, а именно в наличии (1) определения «**талантливого**»  и  (2) приложения «**комедианта**». Такие характеристики говорят **об отступлении** от чисто деловой или нейтральной информации. В этом случае не просто говорится о событии, а задается **стилевая характеристика** всего последующего сообщения. Такой стиль требует от автора  **другого** оформления: в устной речи делается **пауза**, а в письменной она обозначается **тире**.

**3. Насколько такое решение соответствует правилам?**

[У Розенталя это пункт 6 и 10.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111)

**Обособление запятой:**

6. Собственное имя лица или кличка животного выступает в роли обособленного приложения, если поясняет либо **уточняет** нарицательное существительное (перед таким приложением можно без изменения смысла вставить **слова** «а именно, то есть, а зовут его»):  Дочь Дарьи Михайловны, **Наталья Алексеевна**, с первого взгляда могла не понравиться (Т.);

**Обособление тире**

Обратим внимание на то, что при обособлении приложения тире нарицательное существительное  часто уже имеет **другое определение,** согласованное или несогласованное.

10. При обособлении приложений вместо запятой употребляется **тире:**

1. если перед приложением можно вставить слова «**а именно**» (без изменения смысла): В дальнем углу светилось **жёлтое** пятно — огонь квартиры Серафимы (Ж. Г.); Она зарисовала **древние** светильники с гербом города Ольвии — орлом, парящим над дельфинами (Пауст.);
2. перед распространенным или одиночным приложением, стоящим в конце предложения, если **подчеркивается** самостоятельность приложения либо дается разъяснение:  Я не слишком люблю **это** дерево — осину (Т.); В лабазах в два ряда зияли **широченные круглые** ямы — деревянные чаны, глубоко врытые в землю (М.Г.);

**4. Вывод**

*Сегодня похоронили  / талантливого актера и комедианта // —  **Анатолия Викторовича Пронина.***

Мы видим, что постановка тире  действительно имеет определенный **смысл** и соответствует **правилам** Розенталя.

Comment: К сожалению, ни слова не сказали о степени распространенности самого приложения, а ведь это тоже играет роль.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше замечание. Конечно, распространенность оборота влияет на решение в общем случае, но не в этом предложении. Сначала я тоже хотела сделать распространенность основным аргументом, но потом составила интонационную схему без обособления, И вот оказалось, что там все нормально – ни прибавить ни убавить. Значит, надо было найти другое обоснование,  для чего был использован сравнительный анализ.

Comment: Сначала хаяли, что сказал, а потом подхватили.

Comment: Вы это о чем?..

Comment: О "талантливый" и "комедиант". Как же вы злостно говорили, что не надо трогать отдельные слова. И не надо хитрить, вы хотите, чтобы критика касательно вас ушла в чат.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не пишите здесь критику, вы можете дать свой  вариант ответа.

Comment: Вы прикалываетесь? Сами вы критика. Вам уже везде она мерещится. Вы меня критиковали, а в своём ответе написали то, что я говорил, а комментарии с критикой удалили. Значит, дошло. Славно. Надеюсь, что и остальное, что вам говорил (в других местах), в будущем дойдёт.

Comment: @oleedd Подскажите. В слове "одержимый" можно ли корень "держ" выделить?

Comment: @МиМопи С одной стороны, да: нечистая сила держит, по значению похоже на "держимый", значение приставки как в "охваченный". Но этого значения чего-то нет в словарях. Вывел бы это в отдельное значение. В словаре Ушакова сказано, что это первоначальное значение (это в добавочной информации). А при значении "страстно увлечённый" вообще "держать" не улавливается. Иногда бывает, что при одном значении один корень, а при другом другой (корень-то смысловой по определению), но официалы что-то одно выбирают.

Comment: @oleedd Одержимый жаждой мести = держит жажда мести, разве нет?

Comment: @МиМопи Ну здесь ещё да, похоже на "одержимый нечистой силой". А в "одержимый наукой" уже нет, здесь "помешанный". Как видим, расширение области применения увеличило корень. Хотя можно воспринимать буквально, типа наука держит, руководит им, но это надо постараться (неестественно).

Answer (score -1):

Тут отношения с раскрываемым и раскрывающим между определяемым словом и приложением, как в сочетаниях старший бригадир Зырянский, дерево осина, сестра Мария и т. д. Если приложение находится в конце, то обычно ставится тире, вот несколько примеров из справочника Розенталя:

> Было ещё одно препятствие на пути учёных — суеверие островитян.
> Профессия его была самая мирная — учитель.
> Я не слишком люблю это дерево — осину.

Вряд ли кто-то осудит вас, если вы поставите тире, но я бы не стал его ставить, так как в вашем предложении нет предупредительной интонации перед приложением, как  в предложениях выше. В вашем предложении такая же интонация, как в таком предложении: ‟В комнату зашёл старший бригадир Анатолий Павлович Змагин”.

Вот предложение из справочника Розенталя, которое подтверждает то, что ставить что-либо не следует:

> Выступал староста группы Коля Петров.

Вот ещё примеры из сайтов разных:

> В Волгограде 26 апреля скончался советский актер и режиссер Евгений Басилашвили.
> Умер актер и режиссер Вячеслав Ребров, он делал "Гостью из будущего" и "Варвару-красу".
> В Москве в возрасте 65 лет ушел из жизни актер и режиссер Рустам Уразаев.
> Умер узбекский актер и режиссер Мурад Раджабов.

**Ответ:** ничего не нужно ставить.

**ПОЧЕМУ ОТВЕТ SHARON НЕВЕРНЫЙ**

Её ответ заключается в том, что мы обособляем по пункту 6, а вместо запятой ставим тире по пункту 10. Чтобы опровергнуть её ответ достаточно опровергнуть то, что следует обособлять по пункту 6.

Sharon путает отношения с пояснением или уточнением между определяемым словом и приложением и отношения с раскрываемым и раскрывающим.

Отношения с раскрываемым и раскрывающим тогда, когда сперва что-то обозначается неким более общим словом, а потом менее общим, как в таких сочетаниях: бригадир Зырянский, дерево осина, сестра Мария.

Вот несколько предложения с примерами (из справочника Розенталя, кроме одного):

> Дерево осина не очень подходит для сада.
> Выступал староста группы Коля Петров.
> По дороге нам встретился главный инженер Жуков.

Отношения с уточнением или пояснением характеризуются интонацией отступления, то есть человек произносит определяемое слово, делает отступление с некой дополнительной информацией, а потом продолжает предложение. Вот несколько примеров:

> Какая-то ненатуральная зелень — творение скучных беспрерывных дождей — покрывала жидкою сетью поля и нивы (Г.).
> Лёгкие судороги — признак сильного чувства — пробежали по его широким губам (Т.).
> Смотритель ночлежки — отставной солдат скобелевских времён — шёл следом за хозяином (Фед.).
> Память об Авиценне — выдающемся учёном-энциклопедисте, борце за разум и прогресс — дорога для всего человечества.
> Дочь Дарьи Михайловны, Наталья Алексеевна, с первого взгляда могла не понравиться (Т.).

Обратите внимание, что одни и те же слова могут быть как с отношениями пояснения или уточнения, так и с отношениями с раскрывающим и раскрываемым. Но будет ли оно тем или другим зависит не просто от желания произносить так или иначе, а от статуса в контексте. Взгляните на пример:

Участковый, Ершов, заходил к нам вчера и сделал предупреждение. (Важно, что участковый, а ‟Ершов” – это так уж и быть добавлю информация. Здесь отношения с пояснением или уточнением и ‟Ершов” произносится в отступлении.)
Участковый Ершов заходил к нам вчера и сделал предупреждение. (Важно, что Ершов. Здесь отношения с раскрываемым и раскрывающим и ‟Ершов” произносится не в отступлении.)

Вернёмся к пункту Розенталя, по которому Sharon предлагает обособлять:

> 6. Собственное имя лица или кличка животного выступает в роли обособленного приложения, если поясняет либо уточняет-нарицательное существительное (перед таким приложением можно без изменения смысла вставить слова а именно, то есть, а зовут его): Дочь Дарьи Михайловны, Наталья Алексеевна, с первого взгляда могла не понравиться (Т.).

Первое, что следует добавить, что Sharon не упомянула, что у этого пункта есть огромное примечание, которое нельзя было не упомянуть и которое только подтверждает мои слова:

> Примечание. Во многих случаях возможна двоякая пунктуация, в зависимости от наличия/отсутствия пояснительного оттенка значения и соответствующей интонации при чтении. Ср.:
> Вошла её сестра Мария; Сегодня я и друг мой Серёжа уезжаем на юг; Выступал староста группы Коля Петров; По дороге нам встретился главный инженер Жуков.

В этом пункте (без примечания) говорится, что нужно обособлять, когда есть отношения уточнения или пояснения, поэтому он категорически не подходит. В предложении в вопросе нет отношений уточнения или пояснения, а есть отношения с раскрывающим и раскрываемым.

Какая пунктуация для таких отношений.

1. Если приложение не в конце, то обособления вообще нет:

> Дерево осина не очень подходит для сада.
> Сегодня я и друг мой Серёжа уезжаем на юг.
> Участковый Ершов заходил к нам вчера и сделал предупреждение.

2. Если приложение в конце, то обособление тире, если есть предупредительная интонация перед приложением в конце и нет обособления, если нет предупредительной интонации перед приложением в конце.

**Примеры с предупредительной интонацией:**

> Было ещё одно препятствие на пути учёных — суеверие островитян.
> Профессия его была самая мирная — учитель.
> Я не слишком люблю это дерево — осину.

**Примеры без предупредительной интонации в конце:**

> Выступал староста группы Коля Петров.
> По дороге нам встретился главный инженер Жуков.
> У него была фамилия Медведев.

**Ещё один ответ:** В предложении в вопросе отношения с раскрываемым и раскрывающим, приложение в конце, предупредительной интонации перед приложением нет, – поэтому ничего не следует ставить.

Такую пунктуацию подтверждают многочисленные примеры:

> В Волгограде 26 апреля скончался советский актер и режиссер Евгений Басилашвили.
> Умер актер и режиссер Вячеслав Ребров, он делал "Гостью из будущего" и "Варвару-красу".
> В Москве в возрасте 65 лет ушел из жизни актер и режиссер Рустам Уразаев.
> Умер узбекский актер и режиссер Мурад Раджабов.

Если кто-то скажет, что добавление отчества делает приложение распространённым, а в таком случае якобы другая пунктуация, то вот примеры с отчеством:

> 25 февраля 2023 года умер выпускник Минского СВУ 30 выпуска Бычков Игорь Анатольевич.
> 24 июня 2023 года в возрасте 77 лет умер полковник в отставке Лаврик Иван Викторович.
> На 79 году после тяжёлой продолжительной болезни ушел из жизни доктор технических наук, профессор Олег Викторович Мартынов.
> В городском округе Солнечногорск скончался ветеран Великой Отечественной войны Виктор Викторович Байков.
> Там же находился и командир судна, капитан 1-го ранга Николай Викторович Юнг.
> Художница Раиса Григорьевна Геймер — профессору Леониду Викторовичу Кашкину (записка, переданная во время концерта Тесьминова вечером 29 мая).
> ... над громадными плечами голова поручика Виктора Викторовича Мышлаевского. ( М. А. Булгаков. Белая гвардия.)
> Это — сотрудник института истории и философии, профессор Иван Николаевич Понырев.     (М. А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита.)

Нет ни одного примера с тире. Ту часть про то, что слово ‟комедиант” делает это предложение предложением из некого другого стиля, а это как-то влияет на интонацию, я комментировать не буду, потому что опять начну оскорблять. По этой же причине не буду комментировать причину ставить тире из-за всяких палочек. Скажу только, что, скорее всего, слово ‟комедиант” использовано потому, что оно звучит более уважительно, чем ‟комик”.

Ещё добавлю, что моему правильному ответу (с многочисленными примерами, подтверждающими правоту) поставили аж 2 минуса, а ответу Sharon, который, очевидно, неверный, поставили 3 плюса, – это всё многое говорит об уровне компетентности пользователей данного форума. Меня ни капли не удивляет такое невежество участников данного форума.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147509/discussion-on-answer-by-jim-korbett-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: НЕ стоит ориентироваться только на примеры из НКРЯ при объяснении пунктуации. Мало того, что в НКРЯ есть многочисленные ошибки, так и сам по себе НКРЯ не является ресурсом, в котором отражены все возможные варианты: это было бы просто невозможно.